# I want to change individual element counter but when I increment the count it increments all the elements count

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, frontend

What I want is to increment the count for each individual item but when I'm trying to do that it changes for every element rendered. I'm getting data from API and fetching it to redux store and mapping over the array. But could not differ each element.

```
return (
    <View style={styles.Container}>
      {movies ? (
        movies.map((data,i) => {
          const IMAGE_URL = data.image;
          return (
            <Card key={i}>
              <View style={styles.Content}>
                <Card.Cover style={styles.image} source={{ uri: IMAGE_URL }} />
                <ScrollView style={styles.ProductDetails}>
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      fontSize: 15,
                      fontWeight: "bold",
                      paddingBottom: 10,
                    }}
                  >
                    {data.title}
                  </Text>
                  <Paragraph>{data.description}</Paragraph>
                </ScrollView>
              </View>

              <View style={styles.BottomButtonView}>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center" }}>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    key={i}
                    style={styles.ButtonContainer}
                    onPress={() => setCount(count+1)}
                  >
                    <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>+</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>

                  <Text style={{ padding: 10 }}>{count}</Text>

                  <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.ButtonContainer}
                    onPress={() => console.log('dec')}
                  >
                    <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>-</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() => console.log("Added to Cart")}
                  style={styles.AddToCart}
                >
                  <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>${data.price}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </Card>
          );
        })
      ) : (
        <Text>Getting Data....</Text>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Well, if you have an array of elements, you'll need an array of counters. You may also consider extracting these cards into a separate component, that can keep track of its own count.

Answer (score 0):

Updating an Item in an Array :

```
function updateObjectInArray(array, action) {
  return array.map((item, index) => {
    if (index !== action.index) {
      // This isn't the item we care about - keep it as-is
      return item
    }

    // Otherwise, this is the one we want - return an updated value
    return {
      ...item,
      ...action.item
    }
  })
}
```

for Example :

```
const changePrice = (itemArray, item) => {
  return itemArray.map(reduxItem => {
     if(reduxItem.id === item.id){
       reduxItem.price = reduxItem.price + reduxItem.price
     }

     return reduxItem
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you. Hope this will work. However, I solved the problem with a different approach making a new component and it worked.